# Hiding a div still takes up screen real estate

Tags: html, css

Simple enough, I have two divs and am showing one when the browser width is above a certain value, and another when it is below, with this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .desktop {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .mobile {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="desktop">Desktop stuff</div>
<div class=mobile">Mobile Stuff</div>
```

Works fine from a visibility perspective, but it doesn't free up screen real-estate. The space is taken up regardless of whether you can see the div or not.

How do I make a div not just invisible, but also not take up any space while invisible, if that makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: *"but also not take up any space while invisible"* `width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; border:0;` Or did you just mean to use `display: block;` and `display: none;` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `display` style instead of `visibility`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```